# ggplot2 increase spacing between stacked text labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to find a way to increase the spacing between the text labels in my stacked barcharts so that they don't overlap. No amount of vertical adjustment will space them further. 
`geom_text(size = 6, position = position_stack(), vjust = -0.5)` :

[image]

Comment: You could look at using `ggrepel`, here is the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html), which includes examples with text labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using `geom_text_repel()` from the `ggrepel` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(reshape2)   

DF <- read.table(text="Rank F1     F2     
1    300    150    50
2    400    10    10
", header=TRUE)    

DF1 <- melt(DF, id.var="Rank")

ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = variable),
                  nudge_y=0.5,
                  nudge_x=0)
```

[image]